# "Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an object graph" when executing GetMsolUser -All

Tags: powershell, azure, microsoft-office-365

I have an office 365 tenant on which I execute the following command

```
Get-MsolUser -All
```

on server A I get

```
get-msoluser : The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while
trying to deserialize parameter http://provisioning.microsoftonline.com/:ListUsersResult. The InnerException message
was 'Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an object graph is '65536'. Change the object
graph or increase the MaxItemsInObjectGraph quota. '.  Please see InnerException for more details.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-msoluser -All
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Get-MsolUser], NetDispatcherFaultException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException,Microsoft.Online.Administrati
   on.Automation.GetUser
```

On server b talking to the same tenant it works fine. Both have the same versions of the azure active directory powershell commandlets.

From googling around I see you can set the `MaxItemsInObjectGraph` to a higher value, but I do not know where to find the proper config file to do this for powershell. Or even what changed to cause this as up to a few weeks ago the problem server also worked fine.

Comment: How many users do you have in the tenant? Is the issue intermittent on problem server? once error happens do $error[0] | fl * -f . We can then see full stack. And raise a case with Microsoft and provide the logs from %localappdata%\Microsoft\Office365\PowerShell folder to the contact/engineer. I don't know yet if error is coming from AAD or client side based on what you've said so far.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
```

to your **machine.config** in
**C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config**
or for older .NET in:
**C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG**

(Use the **framework64** folder for 64bit, else use the **framework** folder)

The text must be added in the **endpointBehaviours** element.
So mine look like this:

```
<endpointBehaviors>
  <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />    
  <Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior/>  
</endpointBehaviors>
```

Answer (score 0):

A more complete answer for those who use unmodified machine.config -files.

1) Check your powershell version with 
**$psversiontable.psversion.tostring()**

2) Move to folder that corresponds your powershell version
**C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework*\*\CONFIG**

3) Modify machine.config.

Between following lines:

```
</configSections>
<configProtectedData defaultProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
```

Add:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <commonBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </commonBehaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```